“HttpSendRequest failed” error occurred while starting Roblox
I recently started using Arch. 
When I tried running Roblox after installing Wine and Grapejuice,
I encountered this GUI error:

                Roblox <2>

An error occurred while starting Roblox
Details: HttpSendRequest failed
(https://clientsettingscdn.roblox.com/v2/client-version/WindowsPlayer). 
Error: an error occurred in the secure channel support (0x80072f7d).

  (Manually transcribed from this image.)
and I see the error
/usr/bin/xdg-mime: line 885: qtpaths: command not found

in the terminal. 
How do I resolve this error so I can launch Roblox?

References:

What is Wine?  (Wine home page)
Roblox home page
Grapejuice home page
Grapejuice – Easily run Roblox on Linux


Please don’t post images of text, for various reasons; see: PSA: Please don’t post images of text.

Roblox does no longer run on Linux until a further notice. They blocked Wine from launching the game a couple of months ago.

Ah, that would explain why every fix that I’ve tried didn’t work

/usr/bin/xdg-mime: line 885: qtpaths: command not found
the qt5-tools package is missing. Try installing it
pacman -S qt5-tools
